# Sublime Text 2 block editing transform

Tags: text, editor, sublimetext2

how to transform text block to get it in one line
for example

```
Hello
Sublime
Text
Editor!
```

should become
    Hello Sublime Text Editor!
??
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a regular expression to do this. First, select the text:

[image: select text]

Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> on Windows/Linux or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> on OS X to join the lines together:

[image: join lines]

Answer (score 1):

This can be done for example by running a Perl regular expression replace searching for `(?:[\t ]*\r?\n[\t ]*)+` and using a single space character as replace string.

`(?:`...`)` is a non marking group.

`[\t ]*` finds 0 or more tabs or spaces.

`\r?\n` finds an optionally present carriage return and a line-feed.

And the `+` means 1 or more times of the regular expression in the non marking group which in other words finds optionally existing trailing whitespaces at end of a line, the line termination and optionally existing whitespaces at beginning of next line.